# Handling multiple activity with similar URI scheme

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, deep-linking

I am trying Android deep linking in My app. I have two activity, HomeScreen and DetailScreen. Uri scheme of HomeScreen is "www.abc.com" and that of DetailsScreen is "www.abc.com/details". Now when i am clicking any link using uri "www.abc.com/details", Its asking to choose between two activities in Dialog. Is there any way to check android:path for blank.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you please share some code?

Comment: <activity
 android:name=".activity.HomeScreen">
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
       <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.abc.com"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>                                                      
<activity android:name=".activity.DetailsScreenActivity">
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
         <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.abc.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/details/"/>
     </intent-filter>
</activity>

Comment: Just a code sample. You can see that both activity has host as www.abc.com.  when i click link www.abc.com/details/ , Selector dialog is showing both the activity as option. I want to open HomeScreen when i click www.abc.com and DetailScreen when i click www.abc.com/details/.  Thanks for help in advance.